# Menustrip que enliste los formularios mdi hijo, casi terminado

Tags: vb.net

Hola que tal? estoy tratando de hacer que se cree un listo de los formularios MDI hijos, abiertos del formulario actual (Padre), el código es sencillo, agrega items cuando es se agrega un nuevo formulario hijo, pero al eliminarlo y ejecutar el código nuevamente, ejecuta el siguiente error:

> "Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   en mscorlib.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario
>
> Información adicional: Colección modificada; puede que no se ejecute
>   la operación de enumeración."

El código es el siguiente:

```
For Each frm In Me.MdiChildren
            If VentanasToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Count > 0 Then
                For Each item As ToolStripItem In VentanasToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems
                    If TypeOf (item) Is ToolStripMenuItem Then
                        If item.Text.Substring(0, 2) = "- " And item.Text.Substring(2) <> frm.Text Then
                            Dim menuventana As New ToolStripMenuItem() With {.Text = "- " & frm.Text, .Name = frm.Name}
                            VentanasToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(menuventana)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                Dim menuventana As New ToolStripMenuItem() With {.Text = "- " & frm.Text, .Name = frm.Name}
                VentanasToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(menuventana)
            End If
        Next
        'quitar los sobrantes
        If VentanasToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Count > 0 Then
            For Each item As ToolStripItem In VentanasToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems
                If TypeOf (item) Is ToolStripMenuItem Then
                    If item.Text.Substring(0, 2) = "- " Then
                        Dim encontrado As Boolean = False
                        For Each frm In Me.MdiChildren
                            If frm.Text = item.Text.Substring(2) Then
                                encontrado = True
                            End If
                        Next
                       If Not encontrado Then VentanasToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Remove(item)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
```

Se ejecuta en el evento "VentanasToolStripMenuItem.DropDownOpening" 
Alguien encuentra el problema? porque no entiendo, para mi el código esta correcto, espero respuesta! gracias

Answer (score 0):

No me gusta nada la instrucción "For Each frm In Me.MdiChildren". Aunque lo parezca, no se refiere a una lista constante. Cada vez que se realiza un bucle, se vuelve a calcular la lista Me.MdiChildren, lo que puede ser una fuente de errores. Yo escribiría:

Dim listaVentanas = Me.MdiChildren
' Así se calcula el método MdiChildren una vez, no en cada vuelta del bucle.

For Each frm In listaVentanas
' Instrucciones.
Next